# How does the following definition of hyperbolic arc length apply to distance problems? (Differential Geometry)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I have some doubts about the application of the following. Let be the regular surface $\mathbb{H} =$ {$(x,y,z)$ $\in \mathbb{R^3} | z=0, y >0$}. For each point $p =(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{H} $, define the quadratic form $I_p^{\mathbb{H}} (v) : T_p (\mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
\begin{equation} 
    I_p^{\mathbb{H}}(v)= v^T \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{y^2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{y^2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} v
\end{equation}
And let $\alpha : (a,b) \to \mathbb{H} $ a parametrized curve and define the function "hyperbolic arc lenght" as it follows:
\begin{equation}
S^{\mathbb{H}} (t) = \int_a^t \sqrt{I_{\alpha(r)}^{\mathbb{H}} (\alpha ' (r))} dr
\end{equation}.

My question is:
How can we prove, as in the case of the curvature of previous units in differential geometry, that the value is invariant to the parameterization of the curve? Do I use the same procedure as when I got it for normal arc length?
Another question is that, how can I get the length of a segment with that array? How do I apply, for example, the points to get the distance? Excuse me for so many doubts, surely it must be trivial but I can't see it and I have to do a lot of problems using that definition

Comment: The first fundamental form is all you need. Write out the standard reparametrization argument.

Comment: @TedShifrin and how can I apply the distances? for example if they give me a point p_1 and one p_2, with that definition how can I apply it? because as it comes out alone v I get confused . very grateful in advance

Comment: You need a curve, not just points. What do you think a “segment” is?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok! Thanks! <3

Comment: I’m not sure what your text is, but you might find section 2 of chapter 3 of my [free) differential geometry text helpful. The link is in my profile.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I love you haha! Thanks very much!!!!